# Last Non-Null Value in Redshift by Group

Tags: sql, null, amazon-redshift, lag

I am using Redshift and want to receive the last non-Null value by userid.

Here is an example dataset:

```
     Date     UserID      Value
4-18-2018        abc          1
4-19-2018        abc       NULL
4-20-2018        abc       NULL
4-21-2018        abc          8
4-19-2018        def          9
4-20-2018        def         10
4-21-2018        def       NULL
4-22-2018        tey       NULL
4-23-2018        tey          2
```

If the new user starts out with a NULL then replace with 0.

I want my final dataset to look like this:

```
     Date     UserID      Value
4-18-2018        abc          1
4-19-2018        abc          1
4-20-2018        abc          1
4-21-2018        abc          8
4-19-2018        def          9
4-20-2018        def         10
4-21-2018        def         10
4-22-2018        tey          1
4-23-2018        tey          2
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `lag()` and the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select date, userid,
       coalesce(value, lag(value ignore nulls) over (partition by userid order by date)) as value
from t;
```

If the values are increasing, you can also use a cumulative maximum:

```
select date, userid,
       max(value) over (partition by userid order by date) as value
from t;
```

Comment: I created a new column to see the difference and it looks like it is changing the value column by doing this method above. Is it possible to just simply take the value above the null by group (userid) and if there is no userid prior to the null, make it "1"?

Comment: @NickKnauer . . . There should be a `coalesce()` to preserve the existing value.